# find all empty values in JSON object using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to print all empty values in JSON. if all values are not empty then it should print JSON has no empty fields.

```js
  

  let obj = {
  "name" : "abc",
  "sub_name" : "some name",
  "language" : "",
  "skills" : "",
  "device" : "device_name",
  "color" : "",
  
} 



I want to have all the empty keys in JSON


output : 

[language, skills, colour] have empty values
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can combine `Object.keys()` and `Array.filter()` to do it

```js
let obj = {
  "name" : "abc",
  "sub_name" : "some name",
  "language" : "",
  "skills" : "",
  "device" : "device_name",
  "color" : "",
  
} 

let result = Object.keys(obj).filter(b => !obj[b])
console.log(result)
```